# CS50 (Pset4) Filter : Edges

Tags: c, cs50

I'm currently working on Pset4 and my edges function can't seem to get through the CS50 tests. I can't figure out the problem with my code. The errors are-

:( edges correctly filters middle pixel
expected "210 150 60\n", not "255 150 60\n"

:( edges correctly filters pixel on edge
expected "213 228 255\n", not "255 228 255\n"

:( edges correctly filters pixel in corner
expected "76 117 255\n", not "100 117 255\n"

:( edges correctly filters 3x3 image
expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "100 117 255\n2..."

:( edges correctly filters 4x4 image
expected "76 117 255\n21...", not "100 117 255\n2..."

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
RGBTRIPLE imagecopy[height][width];

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        float GxB = 0, GxG = 0, GxR = 0, GyB = 0, GyG = 0, GyR = 0;
        float sobel[3][3] =
        {
            {-1, 0, 1},
            {-2, 0, 2},
            {-1, 0, 1}
        };

        for (int m = -1; m < 2; m++)
        {
            for (int n = -1; n < 2; n++)
            {
                if (i + m > height - 1 || i + m < 0 || j + n > width - 1 || j + n < 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    GxB += image[i + m][j + n].rgbtBlue * sobel[m + 1][n + 1];
                    GxG += image[i + m][j + n].rgbtGreen * sobel[m + 1][n + 1];
                    GxR += image[i + m][j + n].rgbtRed * sobel[m + 1][n + 1];

                    GyB += image[i + m][j + n].rgbtBlue * sobel[n + 1][m + 1];
                    GyG += image[i + m][j + n].rgbtGreen * sobel[n + 1][m + 1];
                    GxR += image[i + m][j + n].rgbtRed * sobel[n + 1][m + 1];
                }
            }
        }

        int B = round(sqrt(pow(GxB, 2) + pow(GyB, 2)));
        int G = round(sqrt(pow(GxG, 2) + pow(GyG, 2)));
        int R = round(sqrt(pow(GxR, 2) + pow(GyR, 2)));

        if (B > 255)
        {
            B = 255;
        }
        if (G > 255)
        {
            G = 255;
        }
        if (R > 255)
        {
            R = 255;
        }

        if (B < 0)
        {
            B = 0;
        }
        if (G < 0)
        {
            G = 0;
        }
        if (R < 0)
        {
            R = 0;
        }

        imagecopy[i][j].rgbtBlue = B;
        imagecopy[i][j].rgbtGreen = G;
        imagecopy[i][j].rgbtRed = R;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        image[i][j] = imagecopy[i][j];
    }
}
return;
}
```

[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exxR1.png)

Comment: "I'm currently working on Pset4 and my edges function" I have no clue what that means, I only know programming. If you want to ask someone who does, ask at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because with the (not) given information it belongs on https://cs50.stackexchange.com (or needs many more details).

Comment: Okay got it, Thank you! I'll be sure to keep this in mind from the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo there:

```
GxR += image[i + m][j + n].rgbtRed * sobel[n + 1][m + 1];
```

It should be `GyR`.